# Brunch build fails with CoffeeScript

Tags: node.js, build, coffeescript, production, brunch

I am trying to build using `brunch build` in my `coffee-script` project. I am getting an error as below:
**Console error:**

```
> test-project@0.0.1 start D:\Data\test project
> brunch build && node server.js

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! test-project@0.0.1 start: `brunch build && node server.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the test-project@0.0.1 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Test.User\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-06-21T12_49_52_118Z-debug.log
```

**Output.log file:**

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'start' ]
2 info using npm@6.9.0
3 info using node@v10.16.0
4 verbose run-script [ 'prestart', 'start', 'poststart' ]
5 info lifecycle test-project@0.0.1~prestart: test-project@0.0.1
6 info lifecycle test-project@0.0.1~start: test-project@0.0.1
7 verbose lifecycle test-project@0.0.1~start: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle test-project@0.0.1~start: PATH: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin;D:\Data\test project\node_modules\.bin;C:\Users\Test.User\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\local\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin;C:\Users\Test.User\bin;C:\Program Files\Microsoft MPI\Bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\Program Files\nodejs;C:\Program Files\dotnet;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Tools\Binn;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Tools\Binn;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\DTS\Binn;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\140\DTS\Binn;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\130\Tools\Binn;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\130\Tools\Binn;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\140\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio;C:\Users\Test.User\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\Test.User\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Program Files\heroku\bin;C:\Python27;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\vendor_perl;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\core_perl
9 verbose lifecycle test-project@0.0.1~start: CWD: D:\Data\test project
10 silly lifecycle test-project@0.0.1~start: Args: [ '/d /s /c', 'brunch build && node server.js' ]
11 silly lifecycle test-project@0.0.1~start: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle test-project@0.0.1~start: Failed to exec start script
13 verbose stack Error: test-project@0.0.1 start: `brunch build && node server.js`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:301:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:198:13)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:198:13)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:982:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:259:5)
14 verbose pkgid test-project@0.0.1
15 verbose cwd D:\Data\test project
16 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.15063
17 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "start"
18 verbose node v10.16.0
19 verbose npm  v6.9.0
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error test-project@0.0.1 start: `brunch build && node server.js`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the test-project@0.0.1 start script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Can someone help me to sort out this issue?

Comment: The error doesn't show anything as such. Try using the `NODE_DEBUG` environment variable to generate more logs https://www.alxolr.com/articles/debugging-tools-and-practices-in-node-js

Comment: @TarunLalwani Let me try.